Azure APIM Standard V2 Custom Domain - RSA-HSM key stored in keyvault - private key issue
Issue:
APIM is on Standard V2 SKU, when attempting to use a custom domain, it needs to obtain a RSA-HSM non-exportable private key cert stored in Key Vault, but although it can read the cert, it results in error message about that cert not having a private key.
Error returned by portal is:

Failed to update API Management service hostnames
Invalid parameter: Certificate '[redacted]' must have a Private Key.

I cannot work out if RSA-HSM certs are not supported by the APIM to KV mechanism or, if its an Azure config reason.
The APIM via managed identity has permissions to the key vault via RBAC roles:
Key Vault Certificate User
Key Vault Certificates Officer
Key Vault Crypto Officer
Key Vault Secrets Officer
I realise that some of these roles are overlapping \ covered by a more privileged role, I was just trying to get all perms that might be needed.
It seems like although the private key is available to the Key Vault itself, the APIM cannot read \ access the private key and therefore, use that cert?

For anyone looking for this answer.
I found that Azure APIM cannot use a certificate that is RSA-HSM backed stored as a cert in [premium] Azure Key Vault.
In key Vault \ certificates, I generated new, creating a new CSR with defaults (size 2048 and RSA), and then used this CSR to get by CA provided cert.
I completed the merge signing request for that cert, then selected this cert from APIM custom domain which then worked.
Note your APIM via its managed identity can access the key vault with RBAC roles - so long as your NSG \ firewall permits the traffic.
